# Display info from user inputs

Tags: sql

Given below are 3 tables.

Table 1: **Borrow**

- Borrow_ID (Primary Key)
- Staff_ID
- Due_Date
- Borrowed_Date
- Customer_ID (Foreign Key from Customer Table)

Table 2: **Feedback**

- FeedBack_ID (Primary Key)
- Customer_ID (Foreign Key from Item Table)
- Item_ID (Foreign Key from Item Table)
- FeedBack_Date
- Description

Table 3: **Customer**

- Customer_ID (Primary Key)
- Name
- Address
- DoB
- Gender
- PhoneNo
- Email

When a user searches for a specific customer's name, I would like to display all the details from the Borrow Table, including the FeedBack from the FeedBack Table. Is there an SQL Statement for this?

Comment: Yes, there is. Did you try something already?

Comment: Hmm, not really, no. But I was thinking something to do with Table Joints, tho I'm not very good at it. xD

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
Borrow.*
FROM Customer 
JOIN Feedback ON Customer.Customer_ID = Feedback_ID.Customer_ID 
JOIN Borrow ON Customer.Customer_ID = Borrow_ID.Customer_ID  
WHERE Customer.Name = 'name';
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I guess it was the JOIN Keyword that I needed. Will try it out tomorrow. :)

Comment: Yea, haha. xD

Sorry for late reply. :)